# Anybody have working example of test case in EcomDevPHPUnit with Magento Enterprise?

Tags: magento-enterprise, ecomdev-phpunit

I have installed EcomDEV PHPUnit extension in Magento Enterprise. I have created Test Case as well. like "Mymage_Myutest_Test_Model_Product" with the proper folder structure.

> class Mymage_Myutest_Test_Model_Product extends
>   EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case { 
>                 /**
>                  * Product count test
>                  *
>                  * @test
>                * @doNotIndexAll
>                 */ 
>          public function productList()   {
>
> ```
>     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
>     // Check that number of items the same as expected value
>     $this->assertEquals(
>         1,
>         $collection->count()
>     );    }  }
> ```

When i run like this phpunit UnitTests.php, it shows "FAILURES!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have mistake in my file name. I got nice link for EcomDev PHPUnit, https://prezi.com/8p7iwxhqzwz_/copy-of-unit-testing-in-magento/